# Laravel: Pass Model Binding to Route Middleware

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware

I have routes that I'm grouping by Location. I need to authorize whether the current user can actually access a particular Location.

I'm wrapping routes in:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => "{location}", 'middleware' => "has-location-access:location"], function() {
...
```

My middleware `handle` method is as follows:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, Location $location)
    {
        $account = Account::find($request->session()->get('account_id'));
        $this->authorize('manageLocation', [$account, $location]);

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Instead of the model being passed into this method, I get a string of `"location"`

`App\Http\Middleware\AuthorizeLocationAccess::handle(): Argument #3 ($location) must be of type App\Location, string given`

How can I simply have it pass the `Location $location` into the `handle` method?

Comment: What is the request url?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think your middleware should be called AFTER the default *SubstituteBindings* middleware which takes care of the route model binding (see :https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.html)

Comment: the route binding is for route actions not middleware ... the parameters to middleware will get passed to the handle method but thats it

Comment: after further review, it does not seem possible to pass the actual param to the middleware. The docs and other examples I see are passing strings only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Location::find($request->route()->location)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do such

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, Location $location)
```

only use

```
function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
```

and to access your passed paramter $location use only $request->location

$request can use as the next

```
$request->formInputName
$request->queryString_Paramter
$request->anyParamter_PassedWithUrlPath
$request->anyParamter_PassedUsing_GetOrPostRouteMethods
```